# How to extract non-duplicate values in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables where each one contains columns with numbers. I need to compare columns in both tables and extract the number that does exist in first table, and does not exist in second one. I don't need unique value.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT Table1.Numbers, Table1.Name
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.Numbers != Table2.numbers
```

Since I am working on several million records can someone recommend more efficient query which would provide me with identical results?

Comment: If you have more records where Table1.Numbers = Table2.Numbers it is better to find those and then filter out them from all records in the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Table1.Numbers, Table1.Name
FROM Table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2 
    WHERE Table1.Numbers=Table2.Numbers
)
```

Other approaches:

[**Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?**](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by checking for the existance on the number in Table2.

```
SELECT  T1.Numbers
        ,T1.Name
FROM    Table1 T1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.Numbers = T1.Numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that your Numbers column are not nullable)

```
SELECT T1.Numbers, T1.Name
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Numbers = T2.Numbers
WHERE T2.Numbers IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Table1.Numbers, Table1.Name
FROM
    Table1, Table2
GROUP BY
    Table1, Table2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```